# onsen ui scroll event is not firing

Tags: javascript, android, events, scroll, onsen-ui

Is it possible to get the scroll event fired with onsen ?
I tried to remove the onsen css file and it worked, the scroll event was fired.
But that's no solution -.-

I also tried the ons-scroller tag but this didn't work too.

Can anyone help me to get the scroll event fired with onsen ui ?

Comment: Having similar issues. I also have an event that doesn't fire in my onsen-ui project. It works when I put the code into my index.html file, but I don't need the script there, I need it on a different page. Have you figured it out yet?

Answer (score 0):

Just adding an eventListener to an element should work, here is an example:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById('container').onscroll = function() {
        console.log("scrolling");
      };
</script>
```

or

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById('container').addEventListener("scroll", function() {
        console.log("scrolling");
      });
</script>
```

Comment: The code is working but the event is not firing anyway because of some onsen css styling ... i tried to remove the css file and it worked. but i dont know exactly what css is preventing the event to fire.